# How does object-fit work with canvas element?

Tags: css, html, html5-canvas, object-fit

I have been unable to find any documentation to tell me one way or another.

Am I able to use object-fit cover on a canvas elements? I have done some experimenting and it is not behaving as expected.

Can somebody give me a definitive answer?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`object-fit`<sup>1</sup> will *only* have an effect when there is a ratio change (a distortion) and applies to only **replaced** element (`canvas` is a replaced element)

Here is a basic example:

```js
var canvas = document.querySelectorAll("canvas");
for (var i = 0; i < canvas.length; i++) {
  ctx = canvas[i].getContext("2d");
  ctx.fillRect(50, 50, 100, 100);
}
```

```css
canvas {
  width: 100px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: block;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid green
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <canvas width="200" height="200"></canvas>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <canvas width="200" height="200" style="object-fit:contain;"></canvas>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <canvas width="200" height="200" style="object-fit:cover;"></canvas>
</div>
```

As you can see I defined a height/width for the canvas to be `200x200` (1:1 ratio) then I change this using CSS thus I break the ratio (we no more have a square) then `object-fit` will correct this.

A related question to understand the difference between setting width/height using attribute and using CSS: [Why box-sizing is not working with width/height attribute on canvas element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53575931/8620333)

---

<sup>1</sup>From [the specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-images-3/#the-object-fit) we can clearly read that all the values (expect the default one `fill`) will try to maintain the ratio:

> contain
>
> The replaced content is sized **to maintain its aspect ratio** while fitting within the element’s content box: its concrete object size is resolved as a contain constraint against the element’s used width and height.
>
> cover
>
> The replaced content is sized **to maintain its aspect ratio** while filling the element’s entire content box: its concrete object size is resolved as a cover constraint against the element’s used width and height.
>
> none
>
> The replaced content is not resized to fit inside the element’s content box: determine the object’s concrete object size using the default sizing algorithm with no specified size, and a default object size equal to the replaced element’s used width and height.

The `none` value is a bit tricky but it basically mean keep the intrinsic default image size without scaling like `contain` or `cover`

```js
var canvas = document.querySelectorAll("canvas");
for (var i = 0; i < canvas.length; i++) {
  ctx = canvas[i].getContext("2d");
  ctx.fillRect(50, 50, 100, 100);
}
```

```css
.box canvas {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: block;
  object-fit:none;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid green
}
```

```html
<canvas width="200" height="200"></canvas>
<div class="box">
  <canvas width="200" height="200" style="width:100px;height:200px;"></canvas>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <canvas width="200" height="200" style="height:50px;width:200px;"></canvas>
</div>
```

Related: [CSS object-fit: contain; is keeping original image width in layout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54375940/8620333)

Comment: Great answer. Just wondering: what's the purpose of the enclosing `<div>`s with corresponding `.box` styling, and the `display: block` in the first snippet? Result looks the same if you remove them, but code clarity would improve imho.