# Grid layout images are not equal height

Tags: css, css-grid

I am using CSS grid to make a layout like below, but the images are not equal height. I though this would be the case by using object-fit...

```css
.row1 {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 5%;
}

img {
  object-fit:cover;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

<div class="row1">
  <div>
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/1550/485/any">
    <p>
      This is some content 1
    </p>
        <p>
      This is a bit longer content that is used to describe something
    </p>
    <p>
      <a href="#">Click Here</a>
    </p>
  </div>
  
    <div>
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/1550/460/any">
    <p>
      This is some content 2
    </p>
    <p>
      This is a bit longer content that is used to describe something, sometimes it can be really long like this example
    </p>
    <p>
      <a href="#">Click Here</a>
    </p>
  </div>
  
    <div>
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/1550/420/any">
    <p>
      This is some content 3
    </p>
    <p>
      This is a bit longer content that is used to describe something
    </p>
    <p>
      <a href="#">Click Here</a>
    </p>
  </div>
  
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

<sup>*The issue is only happening on chrome, Fiferox is rendreing this well*</sup>

> I though this would be the case by using object-fit...

`object-fit` never change the height/width of an element ([CSS object-fit: contain; is keeping original image width in layout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54375940/8620333)). This property is only useful to keep the ratio of the image when this one is distorted ([Object-fit On A Canvas Element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54866986/8620333))

Now the real issue is the use of `height:100%` in this case that is not very intuitive. If we remove it we will have the following:

```css
.row1 {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 5%;
}

img {
  object-fit:cover;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

<div class="row1">
  <div>
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/1550/485/any">
    <p>
      This is some content 1
    </p>
        <p>
      This is a bit longer content that is used to describe something
    </p>
    <p>
      <a href="#">Click Here</a>
    </p>
  </div>
  
    <div>
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/1550/460/any">
    <p>
      This is some content 2
    </p>
    <p>
      This is a bit longer content that is used to describe something, sometimes it can be really long like this example
    </p>
    <p>
      <a href="#">Click Here</a>
    </p>
  </div>
  
    <div>
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/1550/420/any">
    <p>
      This is some content 3
    </p>
    <p>
      This is a bit longer content that is used to describe something
    </p>
    <p>
      <a href="#">Click Here</a>
    </p>
  </div>
  
</div>

</div>
```

Note how in this case the second column is the one with the biggest height thus this one is defining the height of the tracks:

[image]

Now the `height:100%` will be relative to this height defined but it won't work in the second column as it will create a cycle since this column was initially defining the height and only the 1st and 3rd image will get stretched and the text will overflow. *(Firefox is stretching all the columns so not sure wich behavior is the correct one)*

```css
.row1 {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 5%;
}

img {
  object-fit:cover;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

<div class="row1">
  <div>
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/1550/485/any">
    <p>
      This is some content 1
    </p>
        <p>
      This is a bit longer content that is used to describe something
    </p>
    <p>
      <a href="#">Click Here</a>
    </p>
  </div>
  
    <div>
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/1550/460/any">
    <p>
      This is some content 2
    </p>
    <p>
      This is a bit longer content that is used to describe something, sometimes it can be really long like this example
    </p>
    <p>
      <a href="#">Click Here</a>
    </p>
  </div>
  
    <div>
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/1550/420/any">
    <p>
      This is some content 3
    </p>
    <p>
      This is a bit longer content that is used to describe something
    </p>
    <p>
      <a href="#">Click Here</a>
    </p>
  </div>
  
</div>

</div>
```

[image]

You can decrease the content of the second column and the behavior will change since another column will define the height and the image inside the other will get stretched.

```css
.row1 {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 5%;
}

img {
  object-fit:cover;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

<div class="row1">
  <div>
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/1550/485/any">
    <p>
      This is some content 1
    </p>
        <p>
      This is a bit longer content that is used to describe something
    </p>
    <p>
      <a href="#">Click Here</a>
    </p>
  </div>
  
    <div>
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/1550/460/any">
    <p>
      This is some content 2
    </p>
    <p>
      <a href="#">Click Here</a>
    </p>
  </div>
  
    <div>
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/1550/420/any">
    <p>
      This is some content 3
    </p>
    <p>
      This is a bit longer content that is used to describe something
    </p>
    <p>
      <a href="#">Click Here</a>
    </p>
  </div>
  
</div>

</div>
```

---

If you want to have the same height for your image you may need to change the structure of your HTML to make the image a part of the grid and easily stretch them to the same height that you defined. This will work the same in all the borwsers since it doesn't rely on the *strange* behavior of percentage height.

```css
.row1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 150px auto; /*set the width you want*/
  grid-gap: 5%;
}

img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  order:-1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="row1">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/1550/485/any">
    <div>
      <p>
        This is some content 1
      </p>
      <p>
        This is a bit longer content that is used to describe something
      </p>
      <p>
        <a href="#">Click Here</a>
      </p>
    </div>

    <img src="https://placeimg.com/1550/460/any">
    <div>
      <p>
        This is some content 2
      </p>
      <p>
        <a href="#">Click Here</a>
      </p>
    </div>

    <img src="https://placeimg.com/1550/420/any">
    <div>
      <p>
        This is some content 3
      </p>
      <p>
        This is a bit longer content that is used to describe something
      </p>
      <p>
        <a href="#">Click Here</a>
      </p>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

How do you expect the images to look like? If all of them should be the same as the rabbit image, I think it has to do actually with the height you are setting; I changed it to `min-heigth: 100%` instead of `height: 100%` and they all took the same size of the middle one.

The `object-fit` property is only telling the images how to distribute themselves on the space they have, so that shouldn't be the issue.

```css
.row1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 5%;
}

img {
  object-fit: cover;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="row1">
    <div>
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/1550/485/any">
      <p>
        This is some content 1
      </p>
      <p>
        This is a bit longer content that is used to describe something
      </p>
      <p>
        <a href="#">Click Here</a>
      </p>
    </div>

    <div>
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/1550/460/any">
      <p>
        This is some content 2
      </p>
      <p>
        This is a bit longer content that is used to describe something, sometimes it can be really long like this example
      </p>
      <p>
        <a href="#">Click Here</a>
      </p>
    </div>

    <div>
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/1550/420/any">
      <p>
        This is some content 3
      </p>
      <p>
        This is a bit longer content that is used to describe something
      </p>
      <p>
        <a href="#">Click Here</a>
      </p>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

**EDIT**: I notice that the images still look a bit uneven, because the images have different heights; I'd suggest actually setting a height to be used for the image section in the grid-item, so at least that will be consistent on all three items; then the reference for how much space they can use will be the same.

Example with explicit `min` and `max` height:

```css
.row1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 5%;
}

img {
  object-fit: cover;
  min-height: 80px;
  max-height: 120px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="row1">
    <div>
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/1550/485/any">
      <p>
        This is some content 1
      </p>
      <p>
        This is a bit longer content that is used to describe something
      </p>
      <p>
        <a href="#">Click Here</a>
      </p>
    </div>

    <div>
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/1550/460/any">
      <p>
        This is some content 2
      </p>
      <p>
        This is a bit longer content that is used to describe something, sometimes it can be really long like this example
      </p>
      <p>
        <a href="#">Click Here</a>
      </p>
    </div>

    <div>
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/1550/420/any">
      <p>
        This is some content 3
      </p>
      <p>
        This is a bit longer content that is used to describe something
      </p>
      <p>
        <a href="#">Click Here</a>
      </p>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```