# Understanding object-fit CSS property

Tags: html, css, object-fit

In this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) we can read:

> The object-fit CSS property sets how the content of a replaced element, such as an `<img>` or `<video>`, should be resized to fit its container.

What does *container* mean in this case?

Parent element? Containing block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-images-3/#the-object-fit):

> The object-fit property specifies how the contents of a replaced element should be fitted **to the box established by its used height and width**.

So it's neither the parent element nor the containing block but the element itself. It's a relation between the element and it's content. `object-fit` change the behavior of the content based on the dimension of the element.

Example with different elements sharing the same containing block:

```css
img {
  object-fit: cover;
  border: 2px solid;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/10/500/400">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/10/800/400">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/10/500/1000">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/10/600/300">
```

In all the above cases, the `object-fit` will try to cover the `200x200` area desfined by the width/height applied to the element. The containing block/parent element is irrelevant here and play no role.

In the same specification you can also read the keyword "the content box" or "element's content box" which is the *container* your are looking for.

Related:

[How does object-fit work with canvas element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54866986/8620333)

[CSS object-fit: contain; is keeping original image width in layout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54375940/8620333)