Unable to use object-fit: contain with SVG image
Let's have a simple HTML/CSS code (not optimized) as follows:


html,
body {
  background-color: pink;
  height: 100%;
}

div {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background: coral;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
<div>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice"
    viewBox="0 0 24 24" style="object-fit: contain; fill: #000;">
    <path d="M17 12v-.09a.88.88 0 0 0-.06-.28.72.72 0 0 0-.11-.19 1 1 0 0 0-.09-.13l-2.86-3a1 1 0 0 0-1.45 1.38L13.66 11H8a1 1 0 0 0 0 2h5.59l-1.3 1.29a1 1 0 0 0 0 1.42 1 1 0 0 0 1.42 0l3-3a1 1 0 0 0 .21-.32A1 1 0 0 0 17 12z"/>
    <path d="M12 2a10 10 0 1 0 10 10A10 10 0 0 0 12 2zm0 18a8 8 0 1 1 8-8 8 8 0 0 1-8 8z"/>
  </svg>
</div>



The <svg> element contains style property object-fit: contain;; however, it is not working as it should for unknown reasons. If the window is resized, the image is sometimes/often trimmed.

Here is the <img> alternative:


html,
body {
  background-color: pink;
  height: 100%;
}

div {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background: coral;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
<div>
  <img style="object-fit: contain;" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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">
</div>




related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54867171/8620333

@TemaniAfif: But <img> surely is... and it is not working either (see both codes above)

you are not setting any width or height to the image so object-fit will do nothing. Add height: 100%;width: 100%; and it will work

@TemaniAfif: Not with <svg> element (https://jsfiddle.net/ct5p4e9o/), which is weird, as it works with <img> with SVG source.

I gave you the reason: SVG is not a replaced element, img is a replaced element. There is nothing weird

While I was writing the answer, the question was already closed. )) Although in vain.
In your example, you should remove preserveAspectRatio and add svg { width: 100%; height: 100%; }. Then svg will behave like object-fit: contain;, which doesn't work: <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" style="fill: #000; height:100%; width:100%;">

@imhvost - Please provide a jsfiddle working example. I am unable to make it work.

https://codepen.io/imhvost/pen/oNRexre

The issue you're facing is that the object-fit property does not apply to <svg> elements. The object-fit property is specifically designed to work with replaced elements like <img>, <video>, and <object>. SVG elements, when used directly in HTML, are not considered replaced elements, so object-fit has no effect on them.
To achieve the desired effect of containing the SVG within its parent while maintaining the aspect ratio, you can use CSS flexbox properties or transform properties.
Here's a solution using flexbox:


html,
body {
  background-color: pink;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background: coral;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.svg-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
svg {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
<div>
  <div class="svg-container">
    <svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice"
      viewBox="0 0 24 24"
      style="fill: #000"
    >
      <path
        d="M17 12v-.09a.88.88 0 0 0-.06-.28.72.72 0 0 0-.11-.19 1 1 0 0 0-.09-.13l-2.86-3a1 1 0 0 0-1.45 1.38L13.66 11H8a1 1 0 0 0 0 2h5.59l-1.3 1.29a1 1 0 0 0 0 1.42 1 1 0 0 0 1.42 0l3-3a1 1 0 0 0 .21-.32A1 1 0 0 0 17 12z"
      />
      <path d="M12 2a10 10 0 1 0 10 10A10 10 0 0 0 12 2zm0 18a8 8 0 1 1 8-8 8 8 0 0 1-8 8z" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>



Brief Explanation of CSS:

Wrapper Div (.svg-container):
A wrapper div with
display: flex; justify-content:
center; align-items: center; 

ensures that the SVG is centered within the parent div.

SVG Styling:
The SVG itself is styled with max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;
to ensure it scales correctly within the container while maintaining
its aspect ratio.



