# How to make a element fit entire screen instead of viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying to overlay a canvas onto an entire page on a website, but I'm facing some difficulties in doing so.

**There are many similar questions but all of them suggested the usage of height/width 100% and position fixed, to give the illusion that the canvas/element is overlaid on the entire site.**

However, that's not what I'm trying to achieve, **because I'm trying to save the exact position that the a drawing was made on the canvas with respect to  the page, hence it is necessary for me to span it beyond the viewport, supposing that the screen exceeds it.**

Is there a good way to do this? Here is the code:

**css**

```
.canvas-container {
    position: fixed !important;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    ...
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id='${id}'></canvas> <---- Here's the canvas
    <div id="root"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63266793/8620333 ?

Comment: Modern CSS also provides `vw` and `vh` as relative units representing 1% of the view width and height. For example, `50vw` is 50% of the view width.