# how to make canvas fit container div

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, canvas

Im trying to make the canvas fit the section container it is in.
How do i tell the canvas to be the size of its container? I usually just use window.innerWidth. But i want the canvas to resize with its container.
It should be half the page in total as im using 2 grid cols.
I have all the containers set up correctly without the canvas and they fill all available space.
Im using react and calling a Particles component.
Im sure i need to pass the container its in as a prop to my Particles and say something like canvas.width = container.innerWidth
I just cant figure it out. I have tried getting the div the canvas is in by id and then getting its inner width. didnt work.
Sorry i know this is badly explained.

This is the component

```
  function Particles() {
  const useScript = (url) => {

   useEffect(() => {
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  console.log('canvas', canvas);
  console.log('ctx', ctx);
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

  canvas.style.position = 'absolute';
  canvas.style.width = '100%';
  canvas.style.height = '100%';

  const container = document.querySelector('#particles');
  container.appendChild(canvas);
  .....
  };
  return <div id='particles' className=''>{useScript()}</div>;
  }

  export default Particles;
```

and the container

```
<section className='grid lg:h-[calc(100vh-64px)] lg:max-h-[calc(100vh-64px)] bg-green-400 grid-cols-2 h-full'>
      {/* Main */}
      <section className='bg-blue-300 grid overflow-hidden p-2'>
        <section className='bg-yellow-300'>
          <Particles />
        </section>
      </section>
      {/* Form */}
      <section className='bg-red-300 grid'>
        <RegisterForm />
      </section>
    </section>
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938346/canvas-width-and-height-in-html5) answer your question?

Comment: not quite but has a huge amount of useful info.

Comment: answer was found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30229536/how-to-make-a-html5-canvas-fit-dynamic-parent-flex-box-container